# Python: How to remove [' and ']?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove `['` from start and `']` characters from the end of a string.

This is my text:

```
"['45453656565']"
```

I need to have this text:

```
"45453656565"
```

I've tried to use `str.replace`

```
text = text.replace("['","");
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean with "_does not work_"? What does it do?

Comment: just edited the question to be more specific, that start and end are the locations of characters to be removed ;-)

Comment: Note that `text.replace("['","")` will only replace occurrences of the string `['` with the empty string, so you should obtain `"45453656565']"` as result. Doing `text.replace("['", "").replace("']", "")` should return what you want, though there are better solutions.

Comment: `text = text[2:-2]`

Comment: You have the literal representation of a list containing a single string. Why not `ast.literal_eval(text)[0]`? Or, better yet, find out where it came from and get a more useful format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to strip your text by passing the unwanted characters to `str.strip()` method:

```
>>> s = "['45453656565']"
>>> 
>>> s.strip("[']")
'45453656565'
```

Or if you want to convert it to integer you can simply pass the striped result to `int` function:

```
>>> try:
...     val = int(s.strip("[']"))
... except ValueError:
...     print("Invalid string")
... 
>>> val
45453656565
```

Comment: Hello, your code works like a charm. Sorry, I cannot accept this answer because it showed " you can accept the answer in 5 minutes"

Comment: @Nguyen **There is no rush to accept answers.** In fact you should really wait at least a few hours, or one day. Accepting an answer early means less people read your question or attempt to answer it which in turns means you have a less chance of obtaining good answer. most of the time the first answers aren't the better ones.

Comment: @Nguyen I agree with Bakuriu :-) it's better to wait at least for few hours, although this is a simple question but you can always use this tip, specially for more important/complicated questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the character filtering if the element is a digit:

```
>>> number_array =  "['34325235235']"
>>> int(''.join(c for c in number_array if c.isdigit()))
34325235235
```

This solution works even for both `"['34325235235']"` and `'["34325235235"]'` and whatever other combination of number and characters.

You also can import a package and use a regular expresion to get it:

```
>>> import re
>>> theString = "['34325235235']"
>>> int(re.sub(r'\D', '', theString)) # Optionally parse to int
```

Comment: The worst way for solving this problem :-).

Comment: I have updated my answer because you could be interested in a solution with regular expression, that could be better.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.sub`:

```
>>> my_str = "['45453656565']"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("['\]\[]","",my_str)
'45453656565'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hacking your data by stripping brackets, you should edit the script that created it to print out just the numbers. E.g., instead of lazily doing

```
output.write(str(mylist))
```

you can write

```
for elt in mylist:
    output.write(elt + "\n")
```

Then when you read your data back in, it'll contain the numbers (as strings) without any quotes, commas or brackets.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is what I want. I don't need strip anymore

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you found my answer useful please "upvote" it. (You could even change which answer you "accept", if you liked this one better than the currently accepted one.)